# Is there any way that I can get candies faster?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've just started playing the game and it takes very long to get enough candies to progress so is there any way that I can get candies faster or do I have to just?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Mill

You can earn candies faster once you unlock the lollipop farm, once you have around 10,000 lollipops, **The Mill** will appear with a button saying "Unlock the Mill?", you are able to feed the mill and unlock more candies per second, refer to [This](https://candybox2.gamepedia.com/The_Lollipop_farm) Page for more information.